# Replace values on the basis of matching ID variable

Tags: text-processing, awk, join

I have two files. `file1` has 6 columns, `file2` has 2 columns. I want to replace the values in the 6th column of `file1` by the values in column 2 of `file2`, based on matching ID variables (column 1 in both files).

Note: `file2` contains more subjects than `file1`. Therefore the command below did not work unfortunately:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{tmp[$1]=$2;next}{print $0,tmp[$1]}' file2 file1
```

`file1` looks like:

```
HG00096 HG00096 0 0 0 -9
HG00097 HG00097 0 0 0 -9
HG00099 HG00099 0 0 0 -9
HG00100 HG00100 0 0 0 -9
HG00102 HG00102 0 0 0 -9
```

`file2` looks like:

```
HG00096 2
HG00097 5
HG00098 5
HG00099 3
HG00100 3
HG00101 5
HG00102 3
```

I would like the resulting file to look as follows:

```
HG00096 HG00096 0 0 0 2
HG00097 HG00097 0 0 0 5
HG00099 HG00099 0 0 0 3
HG00101 HG00100 0 0 0 5
HG00102 HG00102 0 0 0 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost make it.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{tmp[$1]=$2;next};{$6=tmp[$1] ; print }' file2.txt file1.txt
```

Where:

- `$6 = tmp[$1]` will replace 6th field.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The replacement is indeed what I wanted (instead of adding as I did in my question). I Just found out that the reason why this command did not work is because there are ^M characters in one of my files...

Comment: use dos2unix to get rid of ^M

Comment: Thanks, I use dos2unix on most files I receive from other people, however one this file it didn't work. I used `tr '^M' '\n' < filename` to get rid of the ^M characters.

Answer (score 2):

Use `join`:

```
join -j 1 -o 0,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,2.2 file1 file2
```

Where:

- `-j` defines the join field of both files
- `-o` formats the output as desired

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to comment (no privilege) - but would like to ask an additional question.
I want to do the exact same thing as the first person asked.
In addition i want the remaining lines in file 2 that don't have a match in file 1 to be "-9".
many thanks.
Happy to post a separate question but didn't want to create more posts unnecessarily.

---

file 1

```
HG00096 HG00096 0 0 0 -9
HG00097 HG00097 0 0 0 -9
HG00098 HG00098 0 0 0 -9
HG00099 HG00099 0 0 0 -9
HG00100 HG00100 0 0 0 -9
HG00101 HG00101 0 0 0 -9
HG00102 HG00102 0 0 0 -9
```

---

file 2

---

```
HG00096 2
HG00097 5
HG00099 3
HG00101 5
HG00102 3
```

file 3

---

```
HG00096 HG00096 0 0 0 2
HG00097 HG00097 0 0 0 5
HG00100 HG00100 0 0 0 -9
HG00099 HG00099 0 0 0 3
HG00100 HG00100 0 0 0 -9
HG00101 HG00100 0 0 0 5
HG00102 HG00102 0 0 0 3
```

---

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/420686)

Comment: Kindly ask a new question.